# Android app crashing when adding TabSpec to TabHost - "Resource ID not valid"

Tags: android, android-tabhost, dalvik, tabwidget

I've followed the [Android tutorial for TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), and I'm now trying to modify it by using a layout as well as an activity per tab. Unfortunately, when adding a TabSpec to my TabHost, my app is crashing with a "Resource ID Not valid" error.

I believe the error here is related to Dalvik not understanding my reference to my tab layout XML file, but don't understand why this is the case. I have tried using additional `<include>` statements in my main.xml file, to no avail. Any help would be very welcome!

The crashing Java code:

```
public class TabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    //mTabHost = getTabHost();
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
    Intent intent;

    //Search tab
    intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("search_tab");
    spec.setIndicator("Search", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.magnifyingglass));
    spec.setContent(intent);        
    mTabHost.addTab(spec); //this line crashes


    //Allergies tab - when the above tab is commented out, this tab adds successfully
    intent = new Intent(this, AllergiesActivity.class);
    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("allergies_tab")
            .setIndicator("Allergies", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.man))
            .setContent(intent);

    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

The offending tab's Activity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.search_tab_layout);
}
}
```

The other (working) tab's activity (notice a layout is not specified):

```
public class AllergiesActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Allergies");
    setContentView(textView);

}
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

search_tab.xml - is this not being included somehow?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</LinearLayout>
```

log output:

```
04-09 16:08:23.434: D/ddm-heap(532): Got feature list request
04-09 16:08:23.843: D/AndroidRuntime(532): Shutting down VM
04-09 16:08:23.843: W/dalvikvm(532): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-09 16:08:23.843: E/AndroidRuntime(532): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mattjackson.allergyassassin/mattjackson.allergyassassin.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mattjackson.allergyassassin/mattjackson.allergyassassin.SearchActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050003 type #0x12 is not valid
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mattjackson.allergyassassin/mattjackson.allergyassassin.SearchActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050003 type #0x12 is not valid
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2335)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:648)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at mattjackson.allergyassassin.TabLayoutActivity.onCreate(TabLayoutActivity.java:31)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  ... 11 more
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050003 type #0x12 is not valid
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1870)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:730)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at mattjackson.allergyassassin.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:11)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-09 16:08:23.873: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  ... 20 more
04-09 16:08:23.903: I/dalvikvm(532): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-09 16:08:23.903: E/dalvikvm(532): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your SearchActivity you have to set the layout. You try to set a view( from your layout) as your layout of the activity. Instead of

```
 setContentView(R.id.search_tab_layout);
```

do

```
 setContentView(R.layout.search_tab);
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple mistake, but as an Android noob this was very helpful.